# Why is inversion temperature equal to twice of Boyle's temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

Can you please give me the proof of the following equation?

$$T_{i}= \frac{2a}{Rb}$$

where $T_{i}$ is inversion temperature for a Joule-Thomson experiment on a van der Waals gas. And why is it twice of that of Boyle's temperature?

Comment: Asking this way is not how this site works. Before asking – think, search, read, think, think more. If you still fail to find the answer then ask, but together with explicit summary of ideas a/o results you got until then. Questions that are like duplicates, or are without explicit solving attempts or thoughts,  are usually closed. You get what you paid for. Users  pay here by their own effort.

Comment: Is this supposed to be the inversion temperature for a JT experiment on a van Der Waals gas?

Comment: Yes, your are correct.

Comment: Please go through the [tour](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site (if you haven't yet done so)  to understand some of its rules...

Comment: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142

Comment: On this site "homework" means basic textbook problems. Please edit and add for instance that this refers to a van der Waals gas and JT experiment etc... help us help you. Also, show effort. Why can't you solve this yourself?

Comment: Because I am just a Grade 12 student and I don't have books which show the derivation.

Answer (score 2):

At the Joule-Thomson inversion temperature

$$\mu = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial p} \right)_H = 0$$

It can be shown that

$$ \left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial p} \right)_T=-\mu C_p \tag{1}$$

(this can be derived from the differential form $dH = \left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial p} \right)_Tdp + \left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T} \right)_pdT$)

Also, the thermodynamic equation of state (in terms of enthalpy) is

$$\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial p} \right)_T=V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_p$$

(this can be derived starting from the definition of the enthalpy and the second law,
$dH = -Vdp + TdS$)
which means that at the inversion temperature (see Eq. 1)
$$\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_p=\frac{V}{T} \tag{2}$$
(consistent with the fact that the gas behaves ideally at this point).

For a van der Waals gas

$$(p+\frac{a}{\bar{V}^2})(\bar{V}-b)=RT$$

so that (for one mole)

$$\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_p=\frac{V-b}{T}\left(1-\frac{2a(V-b)^2}{RTV^3} \right)^{-1}$$

so that at the inversion temperature (see Eq. 2)

$$1-\frac{2a(V-b)^2}{RTV^3} =\frac{V-b}{V}=1-\frac{b}{V}$$

or

$$\frac{2a}{RT}\left(\frac{V-b}{V} \right)^2  =b$$

If $b\ll V$ it follows that

$$T_{\mathrm{inv}}  =\frac{2a}{Rb}$$

which is twice the Boyle temperature of a van der Waals gas.